# Proof that using only logical form is valid?

Tags: logic

I'm studying logic. One of the fundamental things that I find everywhere is the claim and I'm quoting wikipedia:

> "The concept of logical form is central to logic, it being held that the validity of an argument is determined by its logical form, not by its content."

And a logical form is defined (on Wikipedia) as follows:

> "The logical form of a sentence (or proposition or statement or truthbearer) or set of sentences is the form obtained by abstracting from the subject matter of its content terms or by regarding the content terms as mere placeholders or blanks on a form."

And they go on to say that:

> "The importance of the concept of form to logic was already recognized in ancient times. Aristotle, in the Prior Analytics, was probably the first to employ variable letters to represent valid inferences."

But why does it work? Why is only the form important and not the subject matter? I mean, is it a fact? **Is there a proof that shows conclusively that this is the case?** Or is it just something that we found to work?

<s>Let me give an informal example. Say we have something like the following (a logical form):</s>

> *X* is better than *Y*.
>   *Y* is better than *Z*.
>   => *X* is better than *Z*.

So we can make the following inference:

> *iOS* is better than *Android*.
>   *Android* is better than *Blackberry*.
>   => *iOS* is better than *Blackberry*.

(Please don't mind if you don't agree with the phone preferences. It's just an example)

Above inference is valid. So far so good. But a weird inference would be:

> *Bad food* is better than *nothing*.
>   *Nothing* is better than *good food*.
>   => *Bad food* is better than *good food*.

This is obviously an invalid inference. So does the subject matter?  Or is it because of natural language issues? "Nothing" perhaps isn't an object and has an implicit negation.

Edit: Thanks guys. I understand the reasoning behind the incorrectness of the example. I would still like to know the answer to my actual question. Can we prove that using logical form alone is enough and it's okay to abstract away the subject matter?

Edit 2: I got very interesting views about this on Philosophy Stack exchange. Here's the link if you're interested: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/26459/proof-that-using-only-logical-form-is-valid

Comment: As for your question on whether it is justified and the proof to the justification that abstract the form alone move away from the subject matter I can't seem to find an answer online anywhere but I'm guessing you should look into justification logic(though its probably pretty advanced) and the justification of validity. I found some sites that might address the question indirectly. I hope they help and I hope someone comes around with answer. Im waiting too.

Site on Justification Logic: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-justification/#MatLogTra

http://www.basicincome.com/bp/zlogic.htm

Comment: With reference to mathematics, considering logical form is about syntactically deducing consequences from axioms. But mathematics is much more than about pure deduction: formulating the right set of (adjusting the) axioms is an art, and we're ultimately interested in the flesh (meaning/semantics) of the results, not just the skeleton (logical force) of the argument/proof.

Answer (score 4):

When you say "nothing", you use two different meanings of the word. The first time, it means "the lack of anything"; the second time, it means "there does not exist anything that..." .

Another explanation: Let G be good food, B be bad food, and N be nothing.

Your phrases are "B is better than N" and "*there is no X so that X* is better than G". We just happen to say the italicized part above in English as the word "nothing".

As for the actual question: If a supposedly logical proof didn't work, then one of the statements must be logically invalid. If something can be transformed into logical form, the original statements don't matter because the transformation into pure logical form by definition keeps qualities the same.

Comment: Thanks Deusovi. It was a good explanation for reasoning behind the example. Any comments on my actual question though?

Comment: So this means that logical reasoning can only be applied to something that can be transformed into logical form and not to everything. I mean, then there is a possibility that there can be something(s) that cannot be logically reasoned. Right?

Comment: @shobhu: Well, any statement can be transformed into logical form. You can always replace an entire statement with a variable. Your question is like asking "Is there any time that the number after 47 isn't 48?" There's not, because 48 is defined as the number after 47. Similarly, logical implication (if A then B) is defined as a situation where as long as A is true, then B is necessarily true. If a logical is flawed, then either there is a problem in the translation from English statement to logical form or you've made a logical error.

Comment: I understand that a logical form doesn't change the meaning and qualities of a statement. But still, why does only the structure matter and not the subject. I'll give an example. For me, _Summer_ is better than _Winter_. (In summers I get to eat ice creams) _Winter_ is better than _Spring_ (I love the snowfall). Logically, _Summer_ is better than _Spring_. But for me it is not. I prefer Spring because it's not as hot. So, how can subject (me in this case) not matter when drawing conclusions? It matters that the I (a human) will not always be logical.

Comment: @shobhu: You believe things that contradict each other. This is not an issue with logic, it's an issue with your preferences; when you say "better", you do not mean the transitive comparison that is used in logic.

Comment: @shobhu: In other words, when you use "better", you mean something different by it each time. It's the same problem that you had with "nothing", except moved to your comparison instead of one of the things you're comparing. (Also, I'm sorry if this comes off as rude - I don't mean this in a mean way at all)

Comment: please don't feel guilty. We're just discussing. I think I sort of get it. In each case I'm changing my reasoning behind deciding what I mean by "better". Also, I had an interesting thought. I guess Logic is "defined" like that... it doesn't always have to be right. I mean it isn't necessary for universe to be logical. As an example it is logical to say that _A_ has to be at one place at one time. So it follows logically that _An electron_ has to be at one place at one time. But it's been proven to be false by quantum mechanics. So the universe doesn't have to obey logic!

Comment: unless _A_ has to be at one place at one time isn't a valid statement.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26917/discussion-between-deusovi-and-shobhu).